# Apply limits to the function while fetching data from mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-decorators

There is a python code which has m number of APIs , which gets request schema with n number of fields and gets the response from mongoDB

I want to write a decorator which limits the response from the mongo

For Ex:

From one of the API, if there are 7 fields in request schema and the expected fields are 2 i.e. id and status. The maximum entries that can be handled for 2 fields are 250

How should be the decorator?

With no clue about decorator. Please suggest

```
    def decorator(func):
        func = validate_parameters(request_schema)(func)
        func = parse_query_parameters(request_schema)(func)
        func = returns_json(func)
        if requires_authentication:
            func = jwt_required(func)
        endpoint = str(uuid4())
        for route in routes:
            blueprint.route(route, methods=methods, endpoint=endpoint)(func)
        flex_schema_by_endpoint[endpoint] = dict(request=request_schema, response=response_schema,
                                             exceptions=exceptions,   requires_authentication=requires_authentication)
         return func
```

Comment: Can you post your APIs?

Comment: Hey @Jay, I have no access to API's please check the attached decorator